# Farthest distance map continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space, and let $A$ be a subset of $X$.

Define $ sd(x) = sup_{a \in A} d(x,a)$.  (Note the supremum, not infimum. The equivalent function with infimum is well known to be continuous)

Is $sd$ a continuous function?

Comment: Assuming that $A$ is bounded show that $|sd(x)-sd(y)| \leq d(x,y)$.

Comment: $A$ is bounded as $X$ is compact, isnt it?

Comment: Right , I didn't notice the compactness hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x,y \in X$ and let $a\in A$ be arbitrary.

Then $d(x,a) \le d(x,y) + d(y,a) \le d(x,y) + \text{sd}(y)$, so the RHS is a fixed upperbound for all distances $d(x,a)$ so that $$\text{sd}(x) \le d(x,y) +\text{sd}(y)$$ and

$$\text{sd}(x) - \text{sd}(y) \le d(x,y)$$

And by interchanging the rôles of $y$ and $x$ we get

$$|\text{sd}(x) - \text{sd}(y)|   \le d(x,y)$$

Which shows that sd is in fact a contraction so uniformly continuous.